# MASM32 lnk2001: unresolved external _WinMain@16

Tags: assembly, linker-errors, masm, masm32

I am following Jeff Huang's [windows assembly tutorial](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf) and essentially copied the code on pages 11-12, yet MASM32 doesn't recognize `WinMain`... Here is my code copied from the .asm file:

initialization & function prototype:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

WinMain proto :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD
```

.data:

```
.data
HelloWorld db "Hello World!", 0
ClassName db "WinClass", 0
AppName db "Somple Window", 0

.data?
hInstance HINSTANCE ?
```

and the code begins:

```
.code
```

start:

```
start:
invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL
mov hInstance, eax
invoke WinMain, hInstance, NULL, NULL, 0
invoke ExitProcess, 0
end
```

with an end start here, I get a linker error for _WinMain@16. The unrecognized WinMain (I added a `global` but it didn't help):

```
global WinMain proc hInst: HINSTANCE, hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR, CmdShow:DWORD
local wc:WNDCLASSEX
local msg:MSG
local hwnd:HWND

mov wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
mov wc.stype, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW
mov wc.lpfnWndProc, offset WndProc
mov wc.cbClsExtra, NULL
mov wc.cbWndExtra, NULL
push hInstance
pop wc.hInstance
mov wc.hbrBackground, COLOR_WINDOW+1
mov wc.lpszMenuName, NULL
mov wc.lpszClassName, offset ClassName
invoke LoadIcon, NULL, IDI_APPLICATION
mov wc.hIcon, eax
mov wc.hIconSm, eax
invoke LoadCursor, NULL, IDC_ARROW
mov wc.hCursor, eax
invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc

invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ClassName, addr AppName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or WS_VISIBLEm CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL
mov hwnd, eax

.while TRUE
    invoke GetMessage, addr msg, NULL, 0, 0
    .break .if (!eax)
    invoke TranslateMessage, addr msg
    invoke DispatchMessage, addr msg
.endw

mov eax, msg.wParam
ret
WinMain endp
```

and WinProc:

```
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
.if uMsg == WM_DESTROY
    invoke PostQuitMessage, 0
.else
    invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd,uMsg, wParam, lParam
    ret
.endif
xor eax, eax
ret
WndProc endp

end start
```

I assemble and link with

```
masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff hello.asm
masm32\bin\link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS hello.obj
```

which are the commands used for the earlier messagebox example, and I understand are the right ones.

Minor note: it's all on my G: drive, but that shouldn't matter.

I get the 2001 unrecognized identifier linker error for _WinMain@16 and _WinMainCRTStartup

I've gone over it again and again, and any other questions I've found that were similar didn't help. Many thanks in advance to anyone who figures out what I'm missing.

Also, I've tried it in VS2010 with MASM, same error unfortunately.

Comment: _"`ml /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS hello.obj`"_ Did you mean `link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS hello.obj` ?

Comment: _"here in the end end start was placed in the tutorial, but it gave me errors during assembly"_ Then you should include those error messages in your question.

Comment: The linker is looking for the *decorated* name, "_WinMain@16".  You only supplied the undecorated one, "WinMain".  Decoration like this is standard for C functions with the __stdcall calling convention.  Learning C first would be advisable.

Comment: @Michael, yes I did mean link, I couldn't copy from the command prompt so I mistyped, fixing it now :) 
The errors were corrected when I moved start back to the top, I believe the problem was in the example code, after all it does not seem logical that functions can be declared inside the start function.

Comment: @HansPassant, I know C, and have worked with the Win32 quite a bit, I can assure you that WinMain is replaced by the linker with the platform-appropriate variant, probably generated during compilation. Plus, I tried using the "decorated" name and the linked looked for a twice decorated name, i.e. when I used _WinMain@16 (not even sure why the @ symbol was acceptable), the linker gave lnk2001 for __WinMain@16@16, I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to use anything more than WinMain

Comment: "but it gave me errors during assembly " ... It is useful to post the errors you are getting for the code you have posted,

Comment: @HansPassant: That's probably not the issue. You typically don't have to add decorations when using MASM. I suspect that the problem has to do with the OP moving the `END` directive, since that signifies the end of the module.

Comment: @user3079666: `start` is just a label. `END start` is you telling the assembler that this is the end of the file, and also that it should use `start` as the entrypoint of the program. Moving that line is probably what's causing your problem, so you should update your question with the error message(s) that you were getting when you had `END start` in the correct place.

Comment: Also, to copy from a Windows terminal, right-click inside the terminal and choose "Select" (or "Highlight" or whatever the option might be named). Then use the mouse to select the text you want to copy, and finally press Enter / Carriage Return to copy the selection.

Comment: @MicroVirus, the errors are all `undefined symbols` on the `local` variables

Comment: @Michael, it just seems strange that the program *must* enter at the first line of code, I've seen the /entry directive around and was pretty sure that you could set where it starts..

Comment: _"it just seems strange that the program must enter at the first line of code"_ It doesn't have to. You can say `END` without specifying any label.

Comment: tried that, it still fails to link with the appropriate version of WinMain and it's CRT startup function, I updated code and errors above

Comment: It looks like you've got 2 `END` directives. You should only have one; at the end of the file.

Comment: @Michael, hold on, before you said I can use `END` without specifying any label... At any rate, as it is now, with the two `END` directives, I get linker errors, if I only keep `end start` in the end I get errors about the local variables and mismatches in my `invoke` commands. If I only keel a simple `end` in the end, I get the same errors. With the two `end` directives, I get the two linker errors, while with `end start` where `start` ends I only get the linker error for _WinMain@16. Two possible locations, four permutations, I listed them all.

Comment: _"hold on, before you said I can use END without specifying any label"_. Right. I never said anything about putting multiple `END` directives in the code. Anyway, the code from the tutorial assembles and links just fine for me. The only change I had to make was to edit the call to `CreateWindowEx` so that all the arguments are on the same line.

Comment: @Michael, I just cross-checked with the code here (http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tut3.html), which is actually the same, I did however  find out that the `global` directive ruins WinMain for some reason, giving the bunch of unrecognized identifier errors.. I don't know what caused the issue in the beginning but it seems to work fine.. I'll keep in mind the thing with the `END` directive though, at least I sort of learned something from all this